# Json Data are not show in html file in angularjs using php files

Tags: javascript, android, json, angularjs, express

How do I set the  php files in angularJS to set the id of any json code?

**Hole and sole this is my final code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="en" ng-app="myBusStopApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>My bus stop - Real time data</title> 
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">   
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>   
        <script type="text/javascript">     

        angular.module('myBusStopApp', [])
    .controller('myBusStopCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        //$scope.realTimeData;

        var url ="http://192.168.1.10/android_connect/JsonReturn.php";
     //   var url = "http://reis.trafikanten.no/reisrest/realtime/getrealtimedata/3010435" + "?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
    alert(url); 
        $http.jsonp(url)

            .success(function(data){
                alert(url); 
                $scope.realTimeData = data;
            });

    }]);</script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin-top:2%;font-size:14px;font-family:Open Sans; padding-left:2%;padding-right:2%;">
    <div ng-controller="myBusStopCtrl">
        <center>
        <div class="table-responsive" style="max-width:800px;">
        <table class="table table-striped" >
            <thead>
                <tr class="info">
                <th>Bus#</th>
                <th>Destination</th>
                <th>Wait time</th>          
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in realTimeData">
                    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.email}}</td>
                    <td>kk</td>            
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </center>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I try any other setting, then it causes a chrome error

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html

And following is my PHP code

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?> 
<?php

        // set up the connection variables
        $db_name  = 'hotel_db';
        $hostname = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';

        // connect to the database
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);

        // a query get all the records from the users table
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM user';

        // use prepared statements, even if not strictly required is good practice
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

        // execute the query
        $stmt->execute();

        // fetch the results into an array
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

        // convert to json
        $json = json_encode( $result );

        // echo the json string
        echo $json;
?>
```

What can i do in this situation

Please help me of this Thanx in advance

in upeer code i have include this

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

but show me error in chrome but i have run this code in android phone

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.10/android_connect/JsonReturn.php. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

Please please help me out of this situation please

Comment: i have a problem in XMLHttpRequest cannot load 192.168.1.10/android_connect/JsonReturn.php. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. In android phone .. When i am include the this in my php files but any answer when i enable in this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi then show me the proper answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add:-

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");

    at the top of php page inside
 <?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");

your code..   

 ?>
```

It allows you to enable cors(cross origin resource sharing).

Comment: I have already Add this in my php file but error show me this <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?> 
but show me error in chrome but i have run this code in android phone

 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.10/android_connect/JsonReturn.php. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
Please please help me out of this situation please I am useing this for android application

Comment: Is your php hosted on any webserver ..??
Or just a simple file ..??

If simple please host it on any server locally then hit it.

Comment: my php file at localserver when i upload this in the  the mobile application then show me {{item.id}} this type of data not original data

Comment: ok here is the best link for you just read it carefully

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3744697/1632286

Comment: change $http.jsonp to $http.get and try it again

Comment: Where i can chage it in this code --------  <script type="application/javascript">
function GetUsers($scope, $http) {
 HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
 dataType: 'jsonp',
    // this is where the JSON from api.php is consumed
    $http.get('http://192.168.1.10/android_connect/JsonReturn.php').
        success(function(data) {
            // here the data from the api is assigned to a variable named users
            $scope.users = data;
        });
}
</script>

Comment: Hey your angular is on server or normla because chrome throws this error in case you are simply running angular in chrome instead for testing you can check it in firefox or deploy your angular to server too.

Comment: When i put the my on server http://eaglenew.comoj.com/JsonReturn.php then show me the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  what can i do in this situation and i can't get it data on web browser

Comment: You are printing table you just need to show json data remove that table tag that is not valid json

Comment: squiroid sir error is remove but data are not show in html file i will try out i this code

Comment: console.log(yourdata) and check is it showing in console ..??

Comment: no data are not show in console this is my js code <script type="application/javascript">
function GetUsers($scope, $http) {
 dataType: 'jsonp',
    $http.jsonp('http://eaglenew.comoj.com/JsonReturn.php').
        success(function(data) {
            // here the data from the api is assigned to a variable named users
            $scope.users = data;
   console.log(users);
        });
}
</script>

Comment: no error in console can i show you to my all code in my upper Question

Comment: Check your request in network and check the response.Use developer console.

Comment: mean's I do not understand this data are proper show in the php file but don't show in the  html file

Comment: press f12 you get console and theis is a network tab in it open it refresh the page and send your call you see the response of your call in that panal.

Comment: JsonReturn.php
eaglenew.comoj.com
GET 200
OK
text/javascript angular.min.js:98
Script
18.7 KB
18.5 KB
3.88 s
2.33 s
 i see this in network tab what is it mean's in this i have no ideas

Comment: That mean data is comming now you have to play with it in front end

Comment: but data are not show in front  end  my front end code is <tr ng-repeat="user in users"><td>{{user.id}}</td><td>{{user.ship_name}}</td><td>{{user.email}}</td></tr>

Comment: please help me out of this situation please

Answer (score 0):

if you returning a json data add the relevant header for json,

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json;
```

Comment: chrome error is solve but the  data are not show in the html file

Comment: what u get on `console.log(data);` on success ajax ?

Comment: i can't get it any answer in console.log(data); in javascript code.

Comment: sir K.Toress i have a problem in  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.10/android_connect/JsonReturn.php. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. In android phone .. When i am include the  this in my php files  but any answer  when i enable in this  extension  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi then show me the proper answer